# Javascript callbacks gets processed faster than others

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the javascript sdk plugin for facebook to create a feed on my webpage.

The problem is that sometimes during load the feed gets unordered, even if i have setup a callback chain.

I think it gets unordered because sometimes the "second" async call gets processed faster than the "first" async call.

This is the first time i've been using callbacks, am i doing it right?

How can i solve the feed gets unordered if some calls finish faster than others?

The code below is only the relevant code and is under working status.

```
function initFeed(){
    FB.api('/{id}/feed', function(response){
    var feedArray = response.data;  
        $.each(feedArray, function(){
            var $this = $(this)[0]; //Status Object for single Status in Feed
            setStatus($this, processStatus); //processStatus is function defined below
        }); 
    });
}

function setStatus(statusObject, callbackProcessStatus){    
    FB.api("/{personId}?fields=id,link,name,picture",
        function (response) {   

        var html = /* Generates html based from statusObject and response */

        callbackProcessStatus(html);        
    });
}

function processStatus(html){
    $('#fb-status-wrapper').append(html);
}
```

(was uncertain on the title of this post, please edit if you think it is not descriptive enough)
Best regards

Comment: `$(this)[0]` can be simplified to just `this`.

Comment: I think you can solve this using promises (`Deferred` in jQuery). Put the promises in an array in the order that you send the calls, and then loop through the array processing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you cannot rely on the order in which the requests will finish. The only way to be sure, is to only call the second one if the first one is done. But that will slow down the loading quite a lot.

Another possibility is to remember for each request which one it is, and insert the items in the right order (insert before a 'later' one, even if that one was received earlier).

I think the easiest way to do that, is to make placeholders for the items inside the each loop, so the placeholders are inserted in the right order. When the requests return, you just place the responses in the right placeholder.

It could look somewhat like this. 2 extra lines and a couple of tiny changes. I couldn't test this without the API, but I hope you get the idea.

```
function initFeed(){
    FB.api('/{id}/feed', function(response){
    var feedArray = response.data;  
        $.each(feedArray, function(index){
            var $this = $(this)[0]; //Status Object for single Status in Feed

            // Make a container per item inside the wrapper.
            var $itemContainer = $('<div></div>');
            $('#fb-status-wrapper').append($itemContainer);

            // Pass the container to the api function.
            setStatus($this, processStatus, $itemContainer); //processStatus is function defined below
        }); 
    });
}

function setStatus(statusObject, callbackProcessStatus, $container){    
    FB.api("/{personId}?fields=id,link,name,picture",
        function (response) {   

        var html = /* Generates html based from statusObject and response */

        // Pass the item place holder/container to the processing procedure.
        callbackProcessStatus(html, $container);        
    });
}

function processStatus(html, $container){
    $container.append(html);
}
```

Comment: Great Solution, works like a charm! I actually did not think of this by myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat common problem with parallel async calls.  The simplest solution requires promises.  I recommend the Bluebird promise library, but most will do fine.

```
var fbApi = function(url){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    FB.api(url, function(resp){ resolve(resp); });
  });
}

function setStatus(statusObject){
  return fbApi("/{personId}?fields=id,link,name,picture")
  .then(function(response){
    var html = ...;
    return html;
  });
}

function getFeedItemPromises(){
  return fbApi("/{id}/feed").then(function(response){
    return response.data.map(function(item){

    });
  });
}
```

Depending on your needs, initFeed could be one of these.  The first renders the feed when all items are available, and the second renders it when each item is available, but enforces the order.

```
function initFeed(){
  return Promise.all(getFeedItemPromises())
  .then(function(itemsHtml){
    // append all of the items at once
    $('#fb-status-wrapper').append(itemsHtml.join("\n"));
  });
}
```

Or this which ensures the order, but eagerly appends items to the feed, after all previous items have been added.

```
function initFeed(){
  function renderItem(html){
    $('#fb-status-wrapper').append(html);
  }

  // reduce can be used to chain promises in sequence
  return getFeedItemPromises().reduce(function(p, nextPromise){
    return p.then(function(){ return nextPromise })
     .then(renderItem);
  }, Promise.resolve())
}
```

An alternative would be to create a div for each item which acts as a placeholder, keep those in an array, and fill them in when each resolves.  This works especially well if you know the height of the items beforehand, and fade them in when they load.  From a UX perspective, this is the best in my opinion.

I would **not** recommend the above if you don't know the heights of items, as it'll cause headache inducing shifting of items as new ones are inserted.

Comment: +1 for using promises, although using jquery just for selecting by id (which is much slower with jquery) and appending stuff is quite the overkill :)

Comment: I did go with GolezTrol solution. Although i tested yours and it works great aswell! But i'm trying to keep down on the external libraries in my app, thats why i did go by the other solution